# Sums of Squares

Tags: sums-of-squares, nt.number-theory

Every prime $p = 4k + 1$ can be uniquely expressed as sum of two squares, but for which
integers $x$ is $x^2 + y^2 =$ some prime $p$?  Stated differently, does the square of
every positive integer appear as one of the squares in the representation of some
prime $p$?

Comment: Even the case $x=1$, i.e. determining primes of the form $n^2+1$ is an open problem.

Comment: But it's known that there is at least one n such that n^2 + 1 is prime.  So the answer for 1 is yes.


Comment: I believe is has not been proved that for every $x$ there is a $y$ such that $x^2+y^2$ is prime. 

Comment: Nice question. I'd like to see an elaboration of Gerry's comment.

Comment: the computational evidence on this is remarkably regular - for p up to about 10**8.
say x (or y) represents p if x**2+y**2 = p.  if we then examine the primes (of form
4k+1) until all positive integers up to m have been used in a representation, then
we will need to examine the first m**2 primes p=4k+1.  the regularity is impressive.
it is also tempting to conjecture that all squares are used equally often (in some asymptotic sense).

Comment: https://oeis.org/A069003

Comment: Or it could be said that you are asking whether there is a Gaussian prime with real part $x.$

Answer (score 21):

If the square of every positive integer appears as one of the squares in the representation of some prime -- that is, if for each $y$ there is an $x$ such that $x^2 + y^2$ is prime -- then it follows that there are infinitely many primes of the form $X^2 + Y^4$ (by restricting to $y$s that themselves are squares).  This corollary happens to be true, but it was a breakthrough result of [Friedlander and Iwaniec](http://www.emis.mi.sanu.ac.rs/EMIS/journals/Annals/148_3/fried1.pdf) from about 15 years ago, so it seems unlikely that the much stronger question the OP is asking has been proven.

Answer (score 6):

This is a special case of [Bateman–Horn conjecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bateman%E2%80%93Horn_conjecture), which in this case states that for given $y\in\mathbb{N}$ the polynomial $p(x)=x^2+y^2$ assumes prime values for infinitely many $x\in\mathbb{N}$, more specifically,
$$\#\{x\leq N: p(x)\text{ is prime}\}\sim\frac{1}{2}\prod_{p\nmid y}\frac{p-1-(-1)^{\frac{p-1}{2}}}{p-1}\cdot\frac{N}{\ln N},$$
thus the asymptotics should depend on $y$, but only by a multiplicative constant.

However the only proved case of Bateman-Horn (at least as far as I know) is for one linear polynomial, ie Dirichlet theorem.